# How to dynamically add an HTML array element[]

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a form where I need to dynamically add as many text fields as the user wants to. I want the text fields to be an array, for example:

```
<input type="text" name="room_text[]">
```

I've already built something I thought would work. It successfully adds more text boxes. I added two more text boxes with javascript dynamically, making the form look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="room_text[]">
      <input type="text" name="room_text[]">
      <input type="text" name="room_text[]">
```

BUT, when I posted it to the PHP file, it only gets the first value. The reason why I know this is a javascript problem is becuase it works fine if you have more than one text box on page load. Its just when you add more text boxes with javascript.

If this helps, this is the jquery function I use to add the boxes:

```
$('.add').live("click", function() {
    var mu = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr');
    var clone = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').clone();
    $(clone).children('td').children('.add').remove();
    $(clone).children('td').children('.redtext').remove();
    $(clone).children('td').children('.remove').css("display", "inline");
    $(clone).css("display", "none");
    $(mu).after(clone);
    $(clone).show("fast");
});
```

Comment: You should check to see what the HTTP transaction looks like. You can use a Firefox plugin like [Tamper Data](http://goo.gl/1AES9) to see the exact state of the outgoing HTTP request when you post the form. If the input elements are showing up on the page, then it's highly unlikely that this is a JavaScript problem.

Comment: make sure the name attribute for the inputs `room_text[]` are being set properly ... if they're all the same then you will experience the behavior mentioned

Comment: Could you just avoid the PHP parameter array-name '[]' processing altogether? Perhaps have the text inputs outside the form, then collect their values on-submit, collate their values into a 'hidden' input (inside the form) and post it to the server.

Comment: @Xander What exactly do you mean by making sure the attribute inputs are being set properly?

Comment: the `name` attribute needs to be unique for each input text field...

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem resides in the `.clone()` function. Can you try a different method, say ...

```
$('.add').live("click", function() {
    var mu = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr');
    var clone = '<tr>' + $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').html() + '</tr>';
    $(clone).children('td').children('.add').remove();
    $(clone).children('td').children('.redtext').remove();
    $(clone).children('td').children('.remove').css("display", "inline");
    $(clone).css("display", "none");
    $(mu).after(clone);
    $(clone).show("fast");
});
```

**UPDATED** - Oops. In that version "clone" is a string, not an element, so the `.children()` functions aren't working ... here's a corrected version:

```
$('.add').live("click", function() {
    var mu = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr');
    var clone = $('<tr>' + $(mu).html() + '</tr>');
    $(clone).children('td').children('.add').remove();
    $(clone).children('td').children('.redtext').remove();
    $(clone).children('td').children('.remove').css("display", "inline");
    $(clone).hide();
    $(mu).after(clone);
    $(clone).show("fast");
});​
```

Comment: There are known issues with older versions of IE and `.clone()` ... something about the "deep copy" functionality, I think.

Comment: I tried the code you send me, it still does the same thing, only reads first element

Comment: Same code works for me -- http://timothyaaron.com/test.php. You sure it's not your PHP?

Comment: I don't think so, but possibly. I did a print_r of $_POST['room_text'] and just gives the first element

Comment: Actually, anything I insert with javascript isnt getting picked up in PHP. Not just the arrays

Comment: After further research, I know its a javascript issue for sure. Becuase, if you inspect an element that is created on page load, go to properties and look at the form, it has the form as an HTMLElement which is fine. But when insepecting an element genereated with javascript, the form property is null

Comment: Well, the code you've provided works just fine (as demonstrated at http://timothyaaron.com/test.php -- I've added the code used to the bottom). In fact, the original code you provided (using `.clone()`) works just fine. Must be some other aspect of your code.